# List<T>: Got only last indexed record

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a method that returns the List of data for Kendo scheduler. My problem is, There are 39 unique records I can get from the DB.

Here also I got the 39 records but **all records are the last indexed record data**:

```
protected object GetData()
        {
            cal_details cal = new cal_details();
            List<cal_details> lst = new List<cal_details>();
            DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                dSet = (DataSet) DAL.SC(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, "", "", "", 1, "tblCal");
                if (dSet.Tables["tblCal"].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    lst.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dSet.Tables["tblCal"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        cal.Description = "Test";
                        cal.isAllDay = true;
                        //cal.OwnerID = 2;
                        cal.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(dSet.Tables["tblCal"].Rows[i]["working_date"].ToString());
                        cal.End = Convert.ToDateTime(dSet.Tables["tblCal"].Rows[i]["working_date"].ToString());
                        cal.OwnerID = dSet.Tables["tblCal"].Rows[i]["date_cat"].ToString();
                        cal.TaskID =i;
                        cal.Title = "Test Title";
                        lst.Add(cal);   
                    }
                }
                return lst;
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent, Content = new StringContent("There were some Errors") });`enter code here`
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same `cal_details` object. You need to create a new object for each row.

Move this line:

```
cal_details cal = new cal_details();
```

inside the `for` loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dSet.Tables["tblCal"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    cal_details cal = new cal_details();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Got it. That silly mistake wasted my time. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You're basically creating one object which you change several times in the loop and then add it several times to a list. It results in a list where all the elements is the same piece of data.

Solution:

Move

```
cal_details cal = new cal_details();
```

into the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dSet.Tables["tblCal"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   cal_details cal = new cal_details();
...
```

Comment: Thank you for Explanation:)